# Is it possible... Are there any tutorials avaialble.. For building a sharepoint Add-in without Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

My employer uses Sharepoint 2013 and my group uses a few SP subsites for various projects.  We want to build an add-in but we want to do it without investing in Visual Studio.  We want to be able to bundle our add-in and hand it over to the Sharepoint Admins to publish on our sites (or do it ourselves if possible)

1. Is that possible to build and package an add-in without VS?
2. Are there any tutorials available that cover this? I haven't found any yet

Thank you.

Comment: You used to be able to create SharePoint-hosted add-ins with `Napa`, but according to the website, it's down since 2017-03-31. Says you should be able to create with Visual Studio Code though with a Yeoman package: https://www.napacloudapp.com/ https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office

Comment: They spent the money on SharePoint and don't want to pop for studio? Just silly. The tutorial request is off-topic, btw.

Comment: Also, you can create very good JS-applications inside SharePoint without creating an Add-in just using SharePoint Designer (or any text editor for that matter).

Comment: We built a proof of concept on using using a content editor.  That worked okay.  We want to be able to publish on a custom page.  Part of the VS issue is who's bucket of money would this come from, another  is security concerns.  Finally our team is composed of Linux users and don't want to take the time and effort to procure windows (either as PC or a VM).

Answer (score 0):

Would Visual Studio Community not work for you? That is the free version that might work. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Comment: Can it be used to create a SP ad-in?

Comment: Sure! The Community version is full featured. Here is a video tutorial on how to get started creating an add-in. https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/14053?l=sMyOE1nmB_3700115881